# how to post the message to the one actor instance at time using akka actor in java

Tags: akka, akka-actor

I have created 5 actor instance using RoundRobinPool with Router. if I put the same 2 message and it will assign to the 2 actor instance and start processing. Because of this I was getting an error. So I want to assign one task at a time to the one instance.Can anyone help me how to do this ?

Comment: Each actor instance processes messages one at a time. Usually, you would use a router when you want to handle multiple messages in parallel. Can you edit the question to explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am using router to process the messages in parallel. We have created 5 instance of it. It start processing parallel as I have placed the same message.I was getting some error.So I want to process the message one by name